# Siegel modular forms in Mathematica

Tags: special-functions

Is there a convenient way to work with Siegel modular forms in Mathematica? I am interested in doing analytic computations using the $\chi_{10}(\Omega)$ Siegel modular form, where $\Omega$ is the $2\times 2$ matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\rho & v \\
v & \sigma
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I am aware that Mathematica has built-in functions for Siegel Theta functions, but I am not sure if these can be used to get $\chi_{10}$. Are there any packages or functions that are specifically designed for working with these forms?

I previously asked this question on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438670/siegel-modular-forms-in-mathematica), but I received a suggestion to also post it here

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica S.E. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: In addition to the welcoming greeting, perhaps you could provide with a mathematical description of the Siegel modular form. You would make the question self-contained and with a clear description you have better chances of getting help :-)